# Sorting by columns

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a table like below.

```
201610  4435230309000131    5969
201601  4435230309000149    5969
201702  4435230309000149    5977
201702  4435230309000156    5962
201612  4435230309000156    7399
201702  4435230309000164    4812
201702  4435230309000172    7230
201702  4435230309000180    5968
201701  4435230309000180    5977
```

I'd like to write a query to return the second and the third column corresponding to the most recent date (the first column).  More specifically, I do not want to see the following records in my result table.

```
201702  4435230309000156    5962
201612  4435230309000156    7399
```

Though, what I want is to retrieve

```
201702  4435230309000156    5962
```

which is associated with the most recent date (201702).

The first column is in "int" format.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to retrieve data as following logic?

```
DECLARE @tb TABLE(col1 INT,col2 VARCHAR(20),col3 INT )
INSERT INTO @tb
SELECT 201610,'4435230309000131',5969 UNION ALL
SELECT 201601,'4435230309000149',5969 UNION ALL
SELECT 201702,'4435230309000149',5977 UNION ALL
SELECT 201702,'4435230309000156',5962 UNION ALL
SELECT 201612,'4435230309000156',7399 UNION ALL
SELECT 201702,'4435230309000164',4812 UNION ALL
SELECT 201702,'4435230309000172',7230 UNION ALL
SELECT 201702,'4435230309000180',5968 UNION ALL
SELECT 201701,'4435230309000180',5977
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT MAX(col1)OVER() AS RecentDay, *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) AS rn1, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col3) AS rn2 FROM @tb
) AS t WHERE t.RecentDay=t.col1 AND t.rn1=t.rn2
```

```
RecentDay   col1        col2                 col3        rn1                  rn2
----------- ----------- -------------------- ----------- -------------------- --------------------
201702      201702      4435230309000156     5962        2                    2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the most recent row, then you can use `top 1` like so:

```
select top 1 *
from t
order by date desc
```

If you are trying to get the most recent row for each of `col2` you can use `row_number()` in a subquery for common table expression like so:

```
select 
    [date]
  , col2
  , col3
from (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
        partition by col2
        order by [date] desc
        )
  from t
  ) as s
where rn = 1
```